# Angular: Define default value input FormField in a FormGroup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

As can be seen in the code below, I'm setting the default value to an text-area:

```
<form [formGroup]="entryForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <div class="view">
            <div class="col">
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <textarea matInput value="Test..." formControlName="firstValue"></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

And i'm initialize my FormGroup and FormFields like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.entryForm = new FormGroup({
   firstValue: new FormControl('')
 });
}

public onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.entryForm.value);
}
```

But when I click on submit, the value of `firstValue` appears to be empty and not with the "Test..." value, like is been defined in the dom element.

Comment: is there a " in `formControlName="firstValue` missing?

Comment: formControlName="firstValue"  quotes is missing

Comment: My bad, didn't paste it right. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Template file : your `formNameControl` is not correct:

You can look this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfbbqs) may this helps you !

```
  <form [formGroup]="entryForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
         <div class="lang">
                <div class="lang-col">
                      <textarea  formControlName="firstValue">   </textarea>

                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
    </form>
```

Class file

```
entryForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.entryForm = new FormGroup({
      firstValue: new FormControl('Test...')
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.entryForm.value);
  }
```

or you can check if `formControlName` is empty then set defualt value

```
  onSubmit() {

    if(this.entryForm.get('firstValue').value == "") {
      this.entryForm.patchValue({
        firstValue: 'Your defualt value goes here'
      }); 
    }
    console.log(this.entryForm.value);
  }
```

Comment: When I click on submit on your demo (without writing into the textarea), the firstValue attribute is empty in the console. But it shouldn't, it should show the value input

Comment: Attributes are defined by HTML. Properties are accessed from DOM (Document Object Model) nodes. The HTML attribute value specifies the initial value; the DOM value property is the current value.

Comment: I recommend to read this once https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property, it helps you to understand better

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
firstValue: new FormControl('')
```

To this:

```
firstValue: new FormControl('Test...')
```

And remove the property value from the text-area:

```
<textarea formControlName="firstValue"></textarea>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygcavn?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts), you can find a full working example (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59072910/5148197) answer)

**Note:**

The problem with this approach is the initial Textarea value will be the "Test...", meaning the user will see such text.

Answer (score 0):

problem in assignment.
you have to assign value of youre entry form after class definition, like this

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
    public entryForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        firsValue: new formControl('')
    });
    constructor()
    ngOnInit()
}
```